# How can I separate specific string after '';'' into new Colum in excel?

Tags: excel, sorting, excel-formula, extract, analysis

I want to separate a string from a Colum which comprise both number and text.

For example: I have this column in my excel file, and I want to extract ''NCT'' containing string into new column. So my question, how can I extract all NCT05718167 sperate column and respective row?

`

**Trial identifier**

```
CTR20223447; NCT05718167;    GDCT0476127; TQB2450-III-12
NCT05671510; GDCT0475865; PRESERVE-003  
NCT05487391; QL1706-304; CTR20222281; GDCT0462845; DUBHE-L-304
```

Comment: Will the NCT text appear only once per row?

Comment: you're looking for regular expressions. 
PS: you are meant to have tried something out after googling and then ask a question and ask anything further than what a simple google search would return. So please...

please look into regex filtering, something like a multiline regex filter (you should be able to find on google) with the filter `(NCT\d{8};)+` should pick out all of your matches

Answer (score 1):

Use TEXTBEFORE and TEXTAFTER:

```
="NCT"&TEXTBEFORE(TEXTAFTER(A1,"NCT"),";")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**A***lternative* approach using <kbd>FILTERXML( )</kbd> , although **[Scott Craner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4851590/scott-craner)** Sir has given you a **simple** and **nice** solution using <kbd>TEXTBEFORE( )</kbd> & <kbd>TEXTAFTER( )</kbd> which works with `MS365` still, note that the following formula given by me won't work with `Excel for Web` & `Excel For MAC` but works with `Excel 2013+` onwards.

---

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `B1`

```
=FILTERXML("<m><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,"; ","</b><b>")&"</b></m>","//b[contains(., 'NCT')]")
```

---

Also it looks like all the `NCT` have a **fixed pattern** and a **len** of `11`, if it has same consistency for your data, then it would be simpler to use the below formula using <kbd>MID( )</kbd> Function.

---

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `B1`

```
=MID(A1,FIND("NCT",A1),11)
```

---